# Laravel sending email

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-web-services

I am trying to send an email from my application that uses the Laravel framework. I have installed Sximo as a theme for working with Laravel and the application is running on Amazon AWS. All seems to be good with the setup as it is working as intended.

I have a API setup on *C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php * that receives data from a mobile application and saves the data to a MySQL table. This also is working as intended.

The idea is that if the API receives some data, an email is generated to a predefined email address. With that, I have a file for receiving the data, writing it to a database and then generating the email as below.

For the Mail section I am following the example on the Laravel website from **[HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail)**

**savequestionnaire.php**

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $questionnairevalues = json_decode($json, true);
    $position = $questionnairevalues['position'];   
    $question_one = $questionnairevalues['question_one'];
    $question_two = $questionnairevalues['question_two'];
    $question_three = $questionnairevalues['question_three'];
    $question_four = $questionnairevalues['question_four'];
    $question_five = $questionnairevalues['question_five'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tb_q (position, question_one, question_two, question_three, question_four, question_five) "
            . "VALUES('$position', '$question_one', '$question_two', '$question_three', '$question_four', '$question_five')";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    if ($result) {
        echo 'Success';
        // Getting error here
        Mail::send('emails.contact.blade', $position, function ($message) {
            $message->from('myEmail@test.com', 'Laravel');
            $message->to('myOtherEmail@test.com');
        });
       echo '\r\nMail sent success';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error';
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

When I run the above code I get the error: "*Success
Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php on line 56*"

I have also tried adding

```
use Mail;
```

to the top of the file but then I get the error: "*Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Mail' has no effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php on line 2*"

How do I go about implementing the Mail feature correctly using Laravel?

I have also tried using PHP's built in

```
mail('myEmail@test.com', 'My Subject', 'My message');
```

function. This generates no errors - but no emails are sent or received.

Comment: did you  change .env file?

Comment: You need to autoload the class(es) in your file, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Hi Shanu k k - No I haven't changed the .env file. Do I simply change the MAIL_HOST, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD to my own email servers details? Will that change the error though I am getting though re. "Class 'Mail' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php on line 56"?

Answer (score 0):

add this at top of controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

In your case directly use :

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('emails.contact.blade', $position, function ($message) {
```

instead of `Mail::send('emails.contact.blade', $position, function ($message) {`

Comment: Tried this but still get error Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php on line 58. Dont get any errors on the use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; however

Answer (score 0):

In Your Config / app.php Check whether there is

```
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
```

under providers. And Check Under Aliases you have

```
   'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
```

**Edit :**

According to the Error, it is looking the facade inside the questionnaire.php  you are now in.  So try putting this code inside of a controller.
To create a controller, in the terminal type,

```
  php artisan make:controller controllerName
```

Comment: Yes have both of those.

Comment: No I get Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php on line 58

Comment: Is this in one your views! Then it seems that php is looking for the Illuminate folder inside the public folder..

Comment: Can you tell me path of the file that you have this code. Isn't it in a Controller?

Comment: The path to the file is C:\xampp\htdocs\public\api\savequestionnaire.php

Comment: Did you try putting this code into a Controller. As it seems to me problem is with the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If this page is standalone, you have to use composer to be able to use Mail:

add

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

at the top of your page (replace the path for matching the location of your `vendor/autoload.php` file